# PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter. My form has multiple rows with same fields name in each row. Could you please help me how can I save it in the database by looping. I'm getting an error

> Error Number: 1048 Column 'sn_unit' cannot be null

Please see the below code. Thank you in advance for your help.

This is the view

```
<?php 
for ($i = 1; $i <= $number_to_check; $i++) {
?>
<hr>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xl-4">
       <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label"><strong><?php echo $i;?></strong></label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sn_unit[]" placeholder="Unit Serial Number" required>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

And this the controller

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($this->input->post('sn_unit')); $i++) {

   $sn_unit = $this->input->post('sn_unit[$i]');
              
   $chk = $this->auth->saveItemReport();
}
```

Comment: `$sn_unit = $this->input->post('sn_unit')[$i];`
try this

Comment: Could you provide us your table script?

Comment: You can simply use foreach to loop all the values.
foreach($this->input->post('sn_unit') as $key => $value){
 $sn_unit = $value;
 $chk = $this->auth->saveItemReport();
}

Comment: What and how are you using the variable `$sn_unit`? What's the point of it? And what does `saveItemReport()` actually do since you call it on each iteration without passing any data to it?

Comment: Please go read [ask], among other things it explains what a halfway proper question title should be phrased like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use foreach to loop through all the values.

```
foreach($this->input->post('sn_unit') as $key => $value)
{ 
   $sn_unit = $value;
   $chk = $this->auth->saveItemReport(); 
}
```

If you still prefer to use for loop; always remember that array starts from 0 index so:

```
$units = $this->input->post('sn_unit');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($units); $i++) {
   $sn_unit = $units[$i];   
   $chk = $this->auth->saveItemReport();
}
```